# Communication with ModEEG through COM port

Tags: c++, c, serial-communication

I want to communicate with device which firmware is described [there](http://openeeg.sourceforge.net/doc/modeeg/firmware/modeeg-p2.c)

[Here](https://gist.github.com/4241153) is my code. But in that code I receive nulls, negative numbers and other trash. What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first make a check to find the synchronization bytes that are first in the message struct. Look for the values 0xA5 and 0x5A. When you find those you can start to decode the rest of the message.

It seems like the ModEEG thing is just outputting a steady stream of bytes so you have to look for the message start markers. Could be good to check those before decoding any message.

Comment: I edited the gist https://gist.github.com/4241968 can't test myself but I think something in the line of that. Also set baud to same as stated in firmware, and note the removal of the two bytes in the struct.

Comment: It's strange, but I got this values as a sync byte: https://gist.github.com/4243338 . Some of them looks like inverted values of desired sync byte

Comment: Solved with using unsigned char